# When Adding IPs with ifconfig eth:xx, how do I in one line find the highest eth:xx

Tags: bash, perl

This will be in a Perl script I need to grab that number and increment it by one for the new IPs. Any one have a one liner for me? Can be Bash/Perl.

*edit*

Given the following input.

```
inet xx.182.137.90/29 brd xxx.182.137.95 scope global eth0
inet xxx.182.137.91/24 brd xxx.182.137.255 scope global eth0:1
inet xxx.182.137.92/24 brd xxx.182.137.255 scope global secondary eth0:2
inet xxx.182.137.93/24 brd xxx.182.137.255 scope global secondary eth0:3
inet xxx.182.137.94/24 brd xxx.182.137.255 scope global secondary eth0:4
```

It should spit out 4. Given what you gave me below

```
$ ip addr | grep -e 'eth[0-9]:[0-9]' | cut -d: -f2
```

If you change your answer to this I will accept it because it helped me get this.

Comment: Do you want eth0, eth1, or eth0:0, eth0:1 types of device names?

Comment: Is it always eth0:xxx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### ifconfig

If I understand what you're asking for, you'd like a one line command that will take the output from `ifconfig` and return the next eth:xx device to use.

So if we have eth0:0, eth0:1, and eth0:2 in use, the command should return 3?

#### Example

A command such as this one should do what you want.

```
$ if (ifconfig | grep -q "^eth"); then \
      echo $(($(ifconfig | grep -Po "(?<=^eth[0-9]:)\d+" | sort -n | tail -1) + 1)); \
      else echo 0;fi
```

So if we have one Ethernet device:

```
$ ifconfig | grep eth
eth0:0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr F0:DE:F1:2F:7D:4E
```

Our command would return a 1:

```
$ if (ifconfig | grep -q "^eth"); then echo $(($(ifconfig | grep -Po "(?<=^eth[0-9]:)\d+" | sort -n | tail -1) + 1)); else echo 0;fi
1
```

If we have no Ethernet devices, then we'll return a 0:

```
$ if (ifconfig | grep -q "^eth"); then echo $(($(ifconfig | grep -Po "(?<=^eth[0-9]:)\d+" | sort -n | tail -1) + 1)); else echo 0;fi
0
```

#### Details

OK it would appear there is a lot going on here but it's pretty straightforward.

1. if statement - initially we need to know if there is *any* Ethernet devices, so we run `ifconfig` and grep the output looking for one. If we find one then we proceed to run `ifconfig` again, and parse it.
2. 2nd ifconfig - Here we're actually parsing the output now. We use `grep`'s PCRE facility (`-P`) to search for the strings that start with ethXX:. The `-o` switch will return the digit that occurs after ethXX:.
3. sort - We then `sort` the results numerically, in case we have multiple ethXX:YY devices.
4. tail - returns the last one, this will the highest valued ethXX:YY device.
5. We then increment this number via the `$(( $(ifconfig ...) + 1 ))`. So if ethXX:YY is 0 we'll get `0 + 1` resulting in a `1`.
6. echo - we then `echo` the results from step 5.
7. If there is no eth device present in the `ifconfig` output, then return 0, since this will be the first one.

#### ip addr

If you'd like to use `ip addr` instead you can use this form of the solution provided above to do so.

```
$ if (ip addr | grep -q "eth"); then \
      echo $(($(ip addr | grep -Po "(?<=eth[0-9]:)\d+" | sort -n | tail -1) + 1)); \
      else echo 0;fi
```

#### Example

Using your sample data:

```
inet xx.182.137.90/29 brd xxx.182.137.95 scope global eth0
inet xxx.182.137.91/24 brd xxx.182.137.255 scope global eth0:1
inet xxx.182.137.92/24 brd xxx.182.137.255 scope global secondary eth0:2
inet xxx.182.137.93/24 brd xxx.182.137.255 scope global secondary eth0:3
inet xxx.182.137.94/24 brd xxx.182.137.255 scope global secondary eth0:4
```

This command would return a 5:

```
$ if (ip addr | grep -q "eth"); then echo $(($(ip addr | grep -Po "(?<=eth[0-9]:)\d+" | sort -n | tail -1) + 1)); else echo 0;fi
5
```

Comment: I think he means if he has `eth0:0` and `eth0:1`, that he wants to get `eth0:2`.

Comment: @Patrick - hmmm. Let's asking him to clarify, what I've provided could be modified fairly easily to do that too. Thanks.

Comment: @user2864066 - did this approach work for you then?

Comment: Actually after some testing this is not what I was looking for. I will clarify in question above. Thank you so far for your help.

Comment: @user2864066 - this is the change I asked you about yesterday.

Comment: @user2864066 - see updates, I've fixed it per your changes. It is still using `ifconfig`, did you actually want it to use the `ip addr` output? You had said that `ip ...` wasn't an option for you.

Comment: ip addr isn't an option when adding, but it's an option to parse from. I'll give you an upvote when I reach 15...

Comment: @user2864066 - I added `ip addr` in case you want it down the road. Also I upvoted your other Q so you now have >15.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a direct answer to your question, but more of an alternate solution.

The alternate solution is to use the [iproute2](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/iproute2) utilities. `ifconfig` is ancient and slowly being deprecated. It's inadequate and isn't capable of fully manipulating the Linux networking stack.

For example, as you know with `ifconfig`, you have to create an alias interface (`eth0:0`, `eth0:1`, etc) for every IP you want to assign to that machine. This is a problem as you can only have 255 interface aliases. With the `ip` command from iproute2 you can assign as many IPs as you want to a single interface.

Example usage:

```
# ip addr show dev enp5s0
2: enp5s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:97:5a:4e:d5:4e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.20/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global enp5s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::ba97:5aff:fe4e:d54e/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

# ip addr add 10.0.0.1/24 dev enp5s0

# ip addr show dev enp5s0
2: enp5s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:97:5a:4e:d5:4e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.20/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global enp5s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 10.0.0.1/24 scope global enp5s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::ba97:5aff:fe4e:d54e/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

You don't need to know anything about the interface's current configuration other than it's name. No having to calculate the next unused interface alias number.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I understand where you are coming from. However, ifconfig works with our gre tunnels and I am forced to use it or ifcfg. Ip addr doesn't always throw out an arp announce ...